# fetch data row wise in smartyy?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I use

```
{foreach from=$fields_array item=v}
```

to fetch from the the table "fields"
the specific types can  be fetched like

```
{if ($listing[$v.caption] || $v.type=="checkbox" || $listing[$v.depending.caption1] || $listing[$v.depending.caption2] || $listing[$v.depending.caption3] || $listing[$v.depending.caption4] ) && $v.type!='price' && $v.type!='checkbox_group' && $v.type!='youtube' && $v.type!='htmlarea' && $v.type!='textarea' && $v.type!='google_maps' && (($v.caption!='make' && $v.caption!='model') || $data_set!="cars")}
```

I want to fetch specific rows..how to do that?

Comment: If the fetching becomes too complex, it's better to do it in PHP and pass the final data to Smarty.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is loop through and display only the rows that match your criteria... but this is generally considered a bad idea.

If you want to filter rows outside of the presentation layer (which is highly advisable) modify the data in your population method of the original variable assignment.  Don't try to do that in smarty.

Comment: how do i loop through n why is that a bad idea if it gets the work done ?

Comment: how do i loop through n why is that a bad idea if that gets the work done?

Comment: $smarty is a template engine, not a data processing engine, it is not optimized for that sort of thing and the efficient place to do filtering is in your data layer.  Using smarty for this can be very slow and consume a lot of unnecessary resources.  Looping is done with your {foreach} ... {/foreach} mechanism.

Comment: okkkkay, that was informative ,,but i think i cant get get to the data layer,, does it contain simple <?php coding in it for further displying it

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i mean  i put data in db from a form but store it temporarily usind &tmp , so that i can display it in the end of form fillng "summary", n after that it gets processed to db, now i added two more fields to the form n also to the db to store it but it aint workin,,,n forget bout the fetching thing, first i need to store it, i actually am using the script from oxyclassiffieds.com

Comment: ...I think this is well out of scope for this question.